# How to use Atheros ath5k driver with aircrack-ng?

Tags: wireless, kernel, aircrack-ng, ath5k

I have read pages and pages of wiki and I'm just more confused than ever as to driver and patches to use with the aircrack-ng suite. The card chipset is `ath5k` but the info is conflicting as to which is the best to use.

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.5.0-22-generic (buildd@lamiak) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) ) #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 2 21:45:40 UTC 2013

lsmod | grep ath5k
ath5k                 135206  0 
ath                    19188  1 ath5k
mac80211              461203  1 ath5k
cfg80211              175574  3 ath5k,ath,mac80211

lsmod | grep mac80211
mac80211              461203  1 ath5k
cfg80211              175574  3 ath5k,ath,mac80211
```

so do I use `ath5k` or `mac80211` and then do I have to blacklist all the others? or am I good to go as I followed the instructions to get to this point but it just seems really confusing and conflicting.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! `mac80211`, `cfg80211` and `ath` with `ath5k` are just modules to work together to provide support for your device. If you would blacklist any of these, it won't work, as your `lsmod` output clearly shows the dependencies of them. Now what is your question exactly? Your title is about getting aircrack-ng to work, the body contains just questions about the kernel modules and how they work together. If it's about aircrack-ng, please provide more information about your attempts, what failed and what errors you got.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same question, but the answer is:

Ath5k is a new, completely FOSS driver for Atheros cards. Wireless-N-enabled Atheros chipsets should use `ath9k` instead. Unlike `madwifi-ng`, this driver is based on the new `mac80211` stack, meaning that it requires `aircrack-ng v1.0-rc1` or newer.

#### Aircrack-ng support

As of `2.6.27-rc2`, `ath5k` can inject without patches (`2.6.26` not tested, `<=2.6.25` is known to be broken). However, injection support is a bit flaky, and speeds are limited to about 50~100pps. To improve injection speed, apply [this patch](http://patches.aircrack-ng.org/ath5k-injection-2.6.27-rc2.patch). It is recommended that you also apply the `mac80211` fragmentation patch for your kernel version, to enable the fragmentation attack. For the released `2.6.27` and `2.6.28` kernels, the `mac80211` patch suffices, no extra patch is needed.

If you have a kernel older than `2.6.26`, it's recommended that you install the latest `compat-wireless-old` package, and apply the `2.6.27` `mac80211` fragmentation patch on the package itself. No `ath5k`-specific patch is needed for either flavor of `compat-wireless`.

Note that in the latest wireless-testing & linux-2.6 kernels, as well as in `compat-wireless-2.6` (but not in `compat-wireless-old`), there is a bug that prevents the fragmentation attack from working properly when no managed interface is brought up on the same PHY as the monitor interface. As a workaround, bring up `wlan0` after creating `mon0` with `airmon-ng`.

**Source:** [Aircrack-ng: ath5k - FOSS driver for Atheros A/B/G/Super-G cards](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=ath5k)